# Tenseorflow Image recognition Execution without output

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition

So currently im using tenseorflow api for image recongition by following along with there tutorial guide for python

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/image_recognition/

Tenseorflow warning log

[image]

My issue is when I execute the command `python classify_image.py`, it attempts to execute outputs a few warnings, then kills the process.

I don't know if it is because of:

> W: Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to
>   work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().

or if it is because of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: the solution was quite simple the server simply ran out of RAM and quit without finishing the code to preserve resources.